# JSON Error: No value for profile_picture

Tags: android, json, android-volley, android-gridview

I have a web service which returns a list of images(profile pictures) and their names and id no. Some of the members don't have profile picture. So I'm adding default picture from drawable. I'm using volley post and pojo to fetch json and add the pictures and names in gridview. But instead of showing images and names, its displaying JSON error message that "No value for profile_picture". [This](http://hastebin.com/ilotupuvod.apache) is my json result. So, any help in getting the images and names would be much appreciated.

```js
Main fragment:

public class SearchName extends Fragment{

    private GridView mGridView;
    private GridItem newItem;
    private GridAdapter mGridAdapter;
    private ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData;
    public static final String KEY_USERID = "user_id", KEY_NAME = "search_text";
    private static final String FETCH_ALL_MEMBERS = "http://example.com/api/member/get-all/";
    String profile_picture = "";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchname, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mGridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        displayLog();

        mGridData = new ArrayList<>();
        mGridAdapter = new GridAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.gridrow, mGridData);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);



    }

    private void displayLog() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, FETCH_ALL_MEMBERS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                            System.out.println(jObj);

                            String status = jObj.getString("status");

                            // Now check status value
                            if (status.equals("0")) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There was some error! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else if (status.equals("1")) {


                                JSONArray result = jObj.getJSONArray("result");
                                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject json_data = result.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String name = json_data.getString("name");
                                    String user_id = json_data.getString("user_id");
                                    //String profile_picture = json_data.getString("profile_picture");

                                    newItem.setName(name);
                                    newItem.setUserId(user_id);
                                    if(json_data.has("profile_picture")){

                                        //String image_def = String.valueOf(R.drawable.default_profile);
                                        newItem.setImage(json_data.getString("profile_picture"));

                                    }else{

                                        Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.sam.fitlincsearch/" + R.drawable.default_profile);
                                        String image_def = path.toString();
                                        newItem.setImage(image_def);

                                    }


                                    mGridData.add(newItem);
                                }


                                mGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } else {
                                // Error in login. Get the error message
                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERID, "1");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

```css
Adapter:

public class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GridItem> {

    private Context mContext;
    int resource;
    private ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData = new ArrayList<GridItem>();

    public GridAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData) {
        super(mContext, resource, mGridData);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mGridData = mGridData;
    }

    public void setGridData(ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData) {
        this.mGridData = mGridData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public GridItem getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridrow, parent, false);
                holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
                holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

            holder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }


            GridItem item = mGridData.get(position);
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                    .load(item.getImage())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                    .fit()
                    .into(holder.image);
            holder.name.setText(item.getName());


        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image, icon;
        TextView name;
    }

}
```

```html
Pojo:

public class GridItem {
    private String nameUrls, imageUrls, sportsCat, userId;

    public GridItem() {
        super();
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return imageUrls;
    }

    public void setImage(String imageUrls) {
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return nameUrls;
    }

    public void setName(String nameUrls) {
        this.nameUrls = nameUrls;
    }

    public String getSportsCat(){
        return sportsCat;
    }

    public void setSportsCat(String sportsCat){
        this.sportsCat = sportsCat;
    }

    public String getUserId(){
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId){
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is you json response? provide that too

Comment: Please check my edited post. Its contains the link.

Comment: You need to check whether the profile picture tag is present or not?  let me add the anwer

Comment: Yes. check if "profile_picture" json tag is present and if not present add a default image.

Comment: check the answer i have added.

Comment: you can use Gson[https://github.com/google/gson] library for json to object. And you can generate json to pojo files in that website http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check the string like this

```
String profile_picture = "";
if(json_data.has("profile_picture")){
    profile_picture = json_data.getString("profile_picture");
}else{
    profile_picture = "";
}
```

your newItem is null.

you need to initialize it first like this inside the for loop

```
newItem = new GridItem();
```

Comment: Still getting the NullPointerException and its in the line  "newItem.setName(name);".

Comment: what is on line 92

Comment: also update the code. i wan to check how did you add the condition that i told

Comment: Line no. 92 is the same which is causing the error.  "newItem.setName(name);" @Mustanser

Comment: Thanks. You are the best.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this, instead of checking to see if profile picture is null you check to see if the JSON contains the profile_picture for example

```
  If (!json_data.has("profile_picture"))){

                                    //String image_def = String.valueOf(R.drawable.default_profile);
                                    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.sam.fitlincsearch/" + R.drawable.default_profile);
                                    String image_def = path.toString();
                                    newItem.setImage(image_def);
                                }else{
                                    newItem.setImage(json_data.getString("profile_picture");
                                }
```